# Function Help -> Organization

Tags: php, oop, function, codeigniter

I am trying to get the following function to run when the link is clicked and then load the previous page, but I seem to end up with a blank page with no php errors:

**View:**

```
<?php if(is_array($get_images)): ?>
            <?php foreach($get_images as $image): ?>
            <img src ="<?=base_url()?>includes/uploads/gallery/thumbs/<?=$image['thumbname']?>" alt="<?= $image['description']?>"> <a href="deleteimage/delete/<?=$image['id']?>">Delete</a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**Controller:**

```
    function delete($id) {

        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->image_model->deleteImage($id);
        $page['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();
        $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
        $data['title'] = 'Delete Gallery Image'; 
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/deleteimage',$page,TRUE);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a destructive thing such as deleting an image should be POST, not GET.

As for the code, something like this should work (assuming that last closing brace means your function is a class method)...

```
// However you extract params in your framework.
$id = $request->getParam('id'); 

// Instantiate the class.
$controller = new ImageController;

// Call the method.
$controller->delete($id);
```